# error display after compile successfully prevent show result view on browser on angular 7 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-components

Problem

I make web API by asp.net core 2.2 and I test success by post man .

after that i open visual studio code and open my angular 7 project to see my web API result

but problem project with angular 7  compiled success but browser not open to

see my result of web API

and give me these error after compile success fully

I write on terminal

ng serve -o

it give me  results as below

```
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
(node:8000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(node:8000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8000) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How to solve this error  to see my result on browser please ?

Actually i need to solve error above because it prevent me from 
see result of angular project on browser .

I try upgrade to angular 8 but this not solve my problem

also npm update on terminal not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with `Angular`, a `Node.js` app running on port 8000 logged this error.

Comment: thank you for reply can you tell me how to log error or which file save log of node i cannot do any thing project not run if possible can you help me

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider to accepting my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. can you please be more specific?

Comment: how to get the reason of that problem and when log file to trace problem this is ambigious problem